# Flagged a question before I saw it in First Posts review queue. I cannot click "I'm Done"

Tags: discussion, support, bug, flags, first-posts

The question which I'm referring to in the title is this: [Error : If you do not go back to the partitioning menu and correct these errors, the partition will be used as is](https://askubuntu.com/q/1288765/1103140)

I flagged this question 2 days ago and it was marked as "helpful".

[image: Screenshot of flag from https://askubuntu.com/users/flag-summary/1103140]

Now, I saw the same post while reviewing posts in First Posts review queue and I cannot click on the "I'm Done" option.

Link to review: https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/1096403

[image: Screenshot of the post from First Posts review queue | Link: https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/1096403]

And the system does know that I've flagged the question already.

[image: Screenshot of flag option of the post in review]

> You have already raised a recommended closure flag

If the system already knows that I've flagged the question, why is the "I'm Done" option non-clickable? Is this a bug?

Comment: just hit 'skip' or "No action needed" in this case.  Because you've already flagged it.